# How to achieve dynamic scrollable buttons menu?

Tags: ios, button, uiscrollview

I am already created dynamic buttons in scroll view but i need to acheive like this way.[image: achieve like this way]

I don't want to change the view controller when I click the buttons only get the button titles on same view controller.I have tried following way to creating buttons in scrollview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var productScrollView: UIScrollView!
 var buttonValues = ["Equity","Commodity","Derivatives","Market","Products","Values"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(buttonSize: CGSize(width:100.0,height:30.0), buttonCount: buttonValues.count)
    productScrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
    productScrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
    productScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    productScrollView.indicatorStyle = .default
    productScrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {
    //creates color buttons in a UIView
    let buttonView = UIView()
    buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    buttonView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
    let padding = CGSize(width:10,height:10)
    buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
    buttonView.frame.size.height = (buttonSize.height +  2.0 * padding.height)
    var buttonPosition = CGPoint(x:padding.width * 0.5,y: padding.height)
    let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width


    for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom) as UIButton
        button.frame.size = buttonSize
        button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
        buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
        button.setTitle(buttonValues[i], for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colorButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonView.addSubview(button)

    }
    return buttonView
}

@objc func colorButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!){
    print(sender.title(for: .normal)!)
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)

}}
```

Comment: You can use this osm library https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I achieve in this way

```
import UIKit

protocol ButtonProtocol{
    func selectedButton(withTag : Int)
}
class ButtonsView: UIView {

    private var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    var buttonProtocolDelegate : ButtonProtocol?
    var movingView : UIView?
    var buttonWidths = [CGFloat]()
    @IBInspectable
    var wordsArray: [String] = [String]() {
        didSet {
            createButtons()
        }
    }
    var padding: CGFloat = 10
    var currentWidth: CGFloat = 0

    private func createButtons() {
        scrollView?.removeFromSuperview()
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width+80, height: self.frame.size.height))
        self.addSubview(scrollView!)
        scrollView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        scrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.calculateButtonWidths()
        let totalWidthOfButtons = buttonWidths.reduce(10.0,+)
        let isBigButton = buttonWidths.contains(where: {$0 > (scrollView?.frame.size.width)!/2})

        for i in 0..<wordsArray.count {
            let text = wordsArray[i]
            var button = UIButton()
            if totalWidthOfButtons >= self.frame.size.width || isBigButton {
                button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:currentWidth, y: 0.0, width: buttonWidths[i], height: self.frame.size.height))
            }else{
                button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:currentWidth, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.size.width/CGFloat(self.buttonWidths.count), height: self.frame.size.height))
                buttonWidths[i] = self.frame.size.width/CGFloat(self.buttonWidths.count)
            }
            button.tag = i
            button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            let buttonWidth = button.frame.size.width
            currentWidth = currentWidth + buttonWidth + (i == wordsArray.count - 1 ? 0 : padding)
            scrollView!.addSubview(button)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        scrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width:currentWidth,height:scrollView!.frame.size.height)
        self.addMovingView()
    }

    func addMovingView(){
        movingView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: (scrollView?.frame.size.height)! - 2, width: buttonWidths[0], height: 2))
        movingView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        scrollView?.addSubview(movingView!)
    }
    @objc func pressed(sender : UIButton){
        self.buttonProtocolDelegate!.selectedButton(withTag : sender.tag)
        self.moveButtonToCenterIfPossible(sender : sender)
    }

    func animageMovingView(sender : UIButton){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20, delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            //Set x position what ever you want, in our case, it will be the beginning of the button
            () -> Void in
            self.movingView?.frame = CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x, y: (self.movingView?.frame.origin.y)! , width: sender.frame.size.width, height: 2)
            self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            // ....
        })
    }

    func moveButtonToCenterIfPossible(sender : UIButton){
        self.scrollView?.scrollToView(button: sender, animated: true)
        //  print(sender.frame)
        self.animageMovingView(sender : sender)

    }

    func calculateButtonWidths(){

        for i in 0..<wordsArray.count {

            let text = wordsArray[i]
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0.0, width: 100, height: 50))
            button.tag = i
            button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
            button.sizeToFit()
            button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 5, left: padding, bottom: 5, right: padding)
            button.sizeToFit()
            let buttonWidth = button.frame.size.width
            buttonWidths.append(buttonWidth)
        }
    }
}

extension UIScrollView {

    func scrollToView(button:UIButton, animated: Bool) {
        if let origin = button.superview {

            // let buttonStart = button.frame.origin
            let buttonCenterPoint = button.center
            var scrollOffset = (origin as? UIScrollView)?.contentOffset
            let offset = scrollOffset
            let deviceBounds = (origin.superview?.frame.size.width)!/2
            //  print(buttonStart, deviceBounds, scrollOffset ?? "0.0")

            let differenceLeft = buttonCenterPoint.x - (scrollOffset?.x)!
            let differenceRight = ((origin as? UIScrollView)?.contentSize.width)! - (contentOffset.x + deviceBounds*2)

            if buttonCenterPoint.x > deviceBounds {
                // scroll left & right
                if differenceLeft > deviceBounds && differenceRight < deviceBounds && differenceRight < button.frame.size.width {
                    //handle last button
                    scrollOffset?.x = (offset?.x)! + differenceRight
                }else{
                    //for all others in the middle
                    scrollOffset?.x = (offset?.x)! + differenceLeft - deviceBounds
                }
                self.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: (scrollOffset?.x)! , y: 0), animated: true)
                // scroll right
            }else {
                // left most buttons
                self.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0 , y: 0), animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonsView: ButtonsView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonsView.buttonProtocolDelegate = self
    buttonsView.wordsArray = ["Offers", "Burgers", "Shakes", "Biryani","Snacks", "Lucknow Biryani","Elepaha","dfasjjlfajd","dafjljafl","546464464"]
}      extension ViewController {
func selectedButton(withTag : Int) {
    print(buttonsView.wordsArray[withTag])
}}
```